# Reading Data from Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, mobile, storage, internal

I am  working with Java in Android Studio to create a mobile app for the business i am working on placement for. I have ran into a problem when trying to store data using Internal memory.

Basically, once the user clicks on a "Start button" i am hoping to saves the users selections behind the scenes to a file and then on the next screen retrieve the stored selections.

Here is the code i have for writing the data to the file (which seems to be working):

```
            int spinnerSelection = myspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int spinnerSelection2 = myspinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String q = quantity.getText().toString();
            String d = duration.getText().toString();
            String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
            TextView endtime = findViewById(endtimetextView);


            String file_name = "Records.txt";
            File file = null;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
            try {
                file = getFilesDir();
                fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file_name, MODE_PRIVATE);

                fileOutputStream.write(spinnerSelection);
                fileOutputStream.write(spinnerSelection2);
                fileOutputStream.write(q.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(d.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(endtimecalc.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(formattedtime.getBytes());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(screen2.this, "SUCESSFULLY SAVED TO " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Please let me know if i need to change any of this code (in particular im not to sure if this is the correct way to save a spinner value which has been selected).

Now, for reading the data into the next screen, i have just been following some different youtube tutorials and none of them have worked out.

Here is some code ive tried:

```
TextView DisplaySaved;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen4);

    DisplaySaved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}


public void read (View view) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("Record.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String lines;

        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null) {
            buffer.append(lines+"\n");
        }

        DisplaySaved.setText(buffer.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

*Also in addition, would anyone know how to create a new record each time instead of it actually overwriting the same file each time? its just i need to store each time a record is created*

Please if anyone could help me out to correct this it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Please be me precise.

Comment: The specific question is - How do i read the data in a new activity from the data i stored in a previous screen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you absolutely need to use files to store this informations, but there are many others way to pass information to a new Activity with Android Studio.

You should check the `Intent` class, you can send a Bundle with your data inside !

Comment: I think it is needed that i have data stored as i will be creating features down the line such as dashboards which i will have to retrieve data from different records.

Comment: What about using a Database so ? I know that you can't reach a database directly with an Android application, but you can use a local database (with SQLite), or, you can communicate with sockets with a server side that will save data to a database, and then, retrieve it with this server or with an API

Comment: @AaronRogers3  you gonna have multiple records, it is a reason to consider about using databases

Comment: I agree @alexay68 a database would be the best way, however, my manager has stated that a database will be added in later iterations and for now the data must be stored "in-app". I have explored using shared preferences but it seems it must be internal storage.?

Comment: Shared preferences isn't the best way to store a "huge" amount of data, for example, you can use it to store a login and a password for a connexion, or a token if you're using token authentification. Database is definitly what you need (it's easier to trace and to control than using files)

Comment: Thanks! @alexay68.. Does the code i have written make any sense or is this possible to achieve using internal storage? or definitely database is the only solution?

Comment: That's the less complicated and the safest way to do what you wants, everything is possible if you have determination and time to do it, but if it's for business, I think that you can't really waste your time right ? ;-)

Comment: isnt `firebase` faster?

Comment: Wow, I didn't heard about that ! It seems great too

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `intent` to pass data through activities example this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId); //putExtra method used to 
send data between activities
 startActivity(intent); //starts activity
```

`Extra_SESSION_ID` is a key that you declare and `sessionId` is the value that you want to pass.

Then in the second activity use this:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

use `getIntent()` to get the intent and `getStringExtra(..)` method to obtain the value in the second activity.

Comment: You came a little too late, that's not exactly what he needs

Comment: @alexay68 im sorry forgive me!

Comment: Yeah but does this also save the data to a file for storage?

Comment: apologies didnt see your comments!

Comment: It saves nothing, it is just giving informations to the new view.

Comment: @AaronRogers3 so you want to save the data to the file which you already did, then you want to read the data from the file on another activity.. right?

Comment: Yes! Although, it is going to be pretty pointless if each time i save it overwrites the previous one, so i would need a new record or "file" to be created each time. Its been a head wrecker lol